# how to fix the error after running my client side react application for the first time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to run my client side application react, but an error appears inside babel, could someone help me fix?

this is my error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/ivo/Área de Trabalho/client/node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js
```

I believe it may be a problem in the version of babel that is outdated within my "cli". I am using babel 6.24.
In the past I tried to change the version of babel, but I was unsuccessful in trying.

this is of my: package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index.js',
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: './main.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'public/img/[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'dist/img/',
          },
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } }, 'sass-loader'],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            minimize: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'dist/fonts',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './resources/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      hash: true,
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
};
```

this is my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
  }
```

I hope that when I execute the command "npm start" the expected result will appear in my browser: hello world

Comment: could you post your webpack config file (and babelrc if there is one.

Comment: I added the contents as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",` with `babel` 6.x - you should use `babel-loader` 7.x (however I'd recommend upgrading babel to 7. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration

For now, try to downgrade your `babel-loader` in package.json to `^7.1.5` - reinstall packages and see if that resolves that error.